# How to update nested knockout obserservable variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, single-page-application

I'm new to TypeScript and trying to figure out why my code is not working as expected.

I have a click binding on a button in my HTML view. The changeDateFormatted function should simple change the text of my dateFormatted string variable to "123". 
My code updates my test variable as expected but for the dateFormatted variable I'm getting the following error:

> _this.invoice(...).dateFormatted is not a function

I can't figure out how else I could or should change the properties of observables within nested classes.

This is my code:

```
import * as ko from 'knockout';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

interface Item {
   name: KnockoutObservable<string>;
   itemNumber: KnockoutObservable<string>;
   amount: KnockoutObservable<number>;
   unitPrice: KnockoutObservable<number>;
}

interface Invoice {
   dateFormatted: KnockoutObservable<string>;
   invoiceNumber: KnockoutObservable<string>;
   items: KnockoutObservableArray<Item>;
}

class InvoiceViewModel {
   public invoice: KnockoutObservable<Invoice> = ko.observable<Invoice>();

   public test: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>("test");

   constructor() {
       fetch('api/SampleData/GetInvoice')
           .then(response => response.json() as Promise<Invoice>)
           .then(data => {
               this.invoice(data);
           });
   }

   public changeDateFormatted = () => {
       this.test('123');
       this.invoice().dateFormatted('123');
   }
}

export default { viewModel: InvoiceViewModel, template: 
require('./invoice.html') };
```

Comment: try initializing it..your code only assigns it a type..

Comment: Please provide the code where you use `InvoiceViewModel`.